# Exception handling in transformer

Tags: spring-integration

We are facing an issue while exception is encountered in transformer.

Below is the scenario:

We have a router and a transformer with the below configuration

```
<bean id="commonMapper"
    class="com.example.commonMapper"></bean>

<int:router input-channel="channelA" ref="commonMapper"
    method="methodA" />

<int:transformer input-channel="channel_2"
    ref="commonMapper" method="methodB"
    output-channel="channelC"></int:transformer>
```

CommonMapper.java :

```
public String methodA(SomeBean someBean) {
    if (<some business condition example someBean.getXValue()>) {
      return "channel_1";
    } else if(<some condition>) {
        return "channel_2";  // Assuming it enters this condition, based on this the above transformer with input-channel="channel_2" gets called
    }else if (<some condition>) {
      return "channel_3";
    } else {
      return "channel_4";
    }
}

public SomeBean methodB(Message<SomeBean> message)
          throws Exception{
    SomeBean someBean = message.getPayload();
    someBean.setY(10/0); // Purposely introducing an exception
}
```

While debugging the application, we found that whenever an exception is encountered in `methodB()`, the control goes back to router reference method i.e. `methodA()` and again satisfy the condition and calls the transformer (with `input-channel="channel_2"`). This repeats for certain iteration. And then exception is logged via `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver -> resolveException`.

Below are the queries:

1. Why does the router gets called again when it encounters an exception in transformer?
2. Is it the bug or the normal behavior?
3. How to tackle this issue?

Please let me know if you need any more details around it.

Comment: Type of the channel that we are using is DirectChannel incase if this is anywhere related for the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Integration flow is just a plain Java methods chain call. So, just looks at this like you call something like: `foo() -> bar() -> baz()`. So, when exception happens in the last one, without any `try...catch` in the call stack, the control will come back to the `foo()` and if there is some retry logic, it is going to call the same flow again.

I'm not sure what is your `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver`, but looks like your talk about this one:

```
Deprecated. 
as of Spring 3.2, in favor of ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver

@Deprecated
public class AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver
extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver

Implementation of the HandlerExceptionResolver interface that handles exceptions through the ExceptionHandler annotation.

This exception resolver is enabled by default in the DispatcherServlet.
```

This means that you use pretty old Spring. I don't think that it is related though, but your top of the call stack is Spring MVC. You need to take a look there what's going on with the retry.

And answering to all you question at once: yes, this is a normal behavior - see Java call explanation above. You need to debug Spring code from the IDE to figure out what is going on the MVC level

Comment: Thanks Artem for the explanation. I will check on retry part.